# AngularJS Directive Design

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been working through AngularJS recently and I have a solid understanding of all of the core concepts. I am building my own application now, and I'm having trouble laying out the blue print, specifically with directive design.

Are there any good open source apps that have well developed directives I could use for some guidance?

I'd love to see how people are approaching real world problems and applications with the use of directives, instead of contrived examples from tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [site](http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/) with a good explanation.

Comment: At first I thought this was a just another tutorial, but they have a section that goes through a sample application. It's not overly complex, but it's a decent start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the built-in [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ng/directive) directives implementation.

You can also take a look at [Angular-UI](http://github.com/angular-ui).

Comment: "Checkout the built-in AngularJS directives implementation." Could you link to a specific file? I'm not sure exactly what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, sure. Here is the directory, which contains all directives https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ng/directive